# NTP over a virtualized Debian

Tags: debian, vmware, ntp

I am having a hard time with NTP configuration on a virtualized (vmware) Linux Debian so I’d like to know if anyone has had the same problem.

Here is the output of the `ntpq –np`:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 200.160.7.193   .GPS.            1 u   49   64  377  174.755  -206752 2697.09
 200.192.112.8   200.19.119.69    2 u   60   64  377  175.449  -210848 4810.03
 200.11.116.1    146.164.48.5     2 u   29   64  377  186.574  -204942 3873.35
 200.160.0.8     200.160.7.186    2 u   31   64  377  173.895  -210291 3875.58
```

Here the output for `ntptrace`:

```
localhost: stratum 16, offset 0.000000, synch distance 0.177945
```

But when I try `ntpdate` I get:

```
13 Dec 14:06:47 ntpdate[4056]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

Any clue of what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a server name when running ntpdate. You also need to shut down ntpd before running ntpdate.

Try this (as root):

```
/etc/init.d/ntp stop
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
/etc/init.d/ntp start
```

Comment: ntpdate pool.ntp.org
13 Dec 14:45:19 ntpdate[4233]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting

Comment: You have to shut down ntpd before running ntpdate.